# OPENSSL SSL_read() get SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL but ERR_get_error() always return 0 when closing the Chrome tab

Tags: browser, https, openssl, libssl

I am currently testing an HTTPS server using Chrome with OpenSSL 3.1.4. Everything appears to be working fine, except for an issue I encounter when closing Chrome tabs.

Upon closing a tab, an EPOLL_IN event is triggered, and subsequent invocations of SSL_read() consistently fail with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. The program then utilizes ERR_get_error() to retrieve the underlying error code, but it always returns 0, indicating no error.

I suspect this might be a default behavior indicating that the remote has forcefully closed the connection, but I am not sure about it, any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.